# Alphabet completion rate

Tags: code-golf

### Introduction

How much of the English alphabet does a given string use? The previous sentence uses 77%. It has 20 unique letters (howmucftenglisapbdvr), and 20/26 ≃ 0.77.

### Challenge

For an input string, return the percentage of letters of the English alphabet present in the string.

- The answer can be in percentage or in decimal form.
- The input string can have upper and lower case, as well as punctuation. However you can assume they have no diacritics or accentuated characters.

### Test cases

Input

```
"Did you put your name in the Goblet of Fire, Harry?" he asked calmly.
```

Some valid outputs

```
77%, 76.9, 0.7692
```

Input:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

All valid outputs:

```
100%, 100, 1
```

The expected output for `"@#$%^&*?!"` and `""` is 0.

Comment: Suggested test cases: `"@#$%^&*?!"`, `""`

Comment: If `77%` and `76.9` is accepted, is `77` accepted too?

Comment: Percentages can have decimal parts too...

Comment: @GrzegorzOledzki Yes of course.

Comment: Are we guaranteed the input will contain at least one letter?

Comment: @Shaggy Based on there being a test case for "", I'm going to assume no.

Comment: @Veskah, that test case wasn't originally there.

Comment: @Shaggy Last edit for OP was 16 hours ago, your answer was at 15 and your comment at 14. I mean, you're right but ???

Comment: If 20/26 may be rounded to 0.7692, 0.769 or 0.77, can I also round it to 0.8, 1 or 0? ;-)

Comment: Is flooring the percentages okay? So, for example, return 76 for the Goblet of Fire testcase?

Comment: `0.7692` is permissible. Is `00.7692`? `a0.7692`? `-0.7692`?

Comment: @Khuldraesethna'Barya `00.7692` is a mathematically valid answer so it's allowed. `a0.7692` and `-0.7692` are not. (why would you put an `a` before a numerical result?)

Comment: @TeleportingGoat I wouldn't :) That was just an attempt to get you going on a slippery slope—allow the `a`, and there's a case to be made for `-0.7692`. Goodbye, 7-byter...

Answer (score 21):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 42 bytes

```python
lambda s:len({*s.upper()}-{*s.lower()})/26
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYyxDoIwFEV3v@KGhWIUE00cTIyLUT/A0aVA0Urpq6UVq/HbERicbk5O7jHB3UivunJ76RSvs4Kj2Sih2WfapN4YYVnynQ@gqB0hWSzXnbFSO1ayONrLAoE8jHfDWmheC0gNdxM4UqaEA5U4SCtmOHFrwy5Cr3hTiQI5V7UKaZwkk3/y3NuHl3mFzFKrUdILd1@bBvQUduwq/g4o6Nr/uh8)

We filter all the non-alphabetic characters out of the string by taking the (set) difference of the uppercase and lowercase representations. Then, we take the length and divide by 26.

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 46 bytes

```python
lambda s:sum(map(str.isalpha,{*s.lower()}))/26
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYyxbgIxEAX7fMUTDXaEDolIKSJFNCjJB1DS7HG@nMH2OmsbMCjffhwpUk0xmok1Dxxexv59NzrybUdIb6l45SmqlKWxiVwcaHF7To3jsxGlf7Verl7HKDZk1av5bGM7VC6IJT8oCOQNbEAeDD65dSaDe3xYMQt8kUhdzzApSkfTYU/Ou9rMtX76X24n@1Ps/ohW@BzQ8wWH4mMCn4z8fR1dKzr@nrrxDg)

Count the unique alphabetic (lowercase) characters, and divide by 26. In Python 2 it would require 3 more characters; two for changing `{*...}` to `set(...)`, and one for making 26 a float: `26.`, to avoid floor division.

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 46 bytes

```python
lambda s:sum('`'<c<'{'for c in{*s.lower()})/26
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYyxbsIwGAZ3nuITixNUUQkkBgTqgmgfgJGhTmITg@0//W1DDeLZQ2BguuF01@XYkp/3er3vrXRVIxGWIblC/IpVvRI3oYlRw/jbJEwtXRQX5b38nC36jo2PhS7EeGMaZEroUnyS4aVTQ4LYKnxTZVUEaWwNqw/8SOb8NcagZDipBrW0zuapKMvRe7kb7F8y9QkV08VD0z@OyXUBdFb8@lp5zWjoMHT9Aw)

Same length, essentially the same as the previous one, but without "built-in" string method.

Comment: Why does the second one return `1.0` and not `1`? (I didn't want to specifically disallow it so it wouldn't disadvantage specific languages, but I'm curious)

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Division with a single slash always gives floats in Python 3, even if the operands are integers. For integer division, you'd use `//`, but then it would always be integer division, which is obviously not what we want here. It makes sense that they didn't make the data type of the output dependent on the specific values of the operands, which means always floats, even if it's a whole number.

Answer (score 11):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 8 bytes

```
2Y2jkmYm
```

Try it at [MATL Online](https://matl.io/?code=2Y2jkmYm&inputs=%22Did+you+put+your+name+in+the+Goblet+of+Fire%2C+Harry%3F%22+he+asked+calmly.&version=20.11.0)

**Explanation**

```
2Y2    % Predefined literal for 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
j      % Explicitly grab input as a string
k      % Convert to lower-case
m      % Check for membership of the alphabet characters in the string. 
       % Results in a 26-element array with a 1 where a given character in 
       % the alphabet string was present in the input and a 0 otherwise
Ym     % Compute the mean of this array to yield the percentage as a decimal
       % Implicitly display the result
```

Answer (score 8):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) / MATLAB, 33 bytes

```matlab
@(s)mean(any(65:90==upper(s)',1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FclLCsIwFEbhrfx0kgRK0IGCQtCBqNu4tjdYzIs0EbL6WEcHvhOnQl/u1mit@1WuyjMFSaHJ4@F82hlTU@K8uRj3SnUrxXBbZrRYkWr5NyOQZywB5c14xJfjgmhxXzKPeFLO7TJgW7R@eMZEzrumheo/)

#### Explanation

```matlab
@(s)                               % Anonymous function with input s: row vector of chars
             65:90                 % Row vector with ASCII codes of uppercase letters
                    upper(s)       % Input converted to uppercase
                            '      % Transform into column vector
                  ==               % Equality test, element-wise with broadcast. Gives a
                                   % matrix containing true and false
         any(                ,1)   % Row vector containing true for columns that have at
                                   % least one entry with value true
    mean(                       )  % Mean
```

Answer (score 8):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>8</s> <s>7</s> 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
lASåÅA
```

-1 byte thanks to *@LuisMendo*.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/xzH48NLDrY7//yu5ZKYoVOaXKhSUloDoIoW8xNxUhcw8hZKMVAX3/KSc1BKF/DQFt8yiVB0Fj8Siokp7JQWgVGJxdmqKQnJiTm5OpR4A) or [verify a few more test cases](https://tio.run/##HY5BbsIwFET3OcU0pSwQ6hUCEgX2sEb6ST6Ji@Mf7DjUVbflANyBk3ATLhIMq5FmNE9PHOWKh78@ZCnu5wvSLAx6vrldb//zYTqs5YTGFzVkj65mfJlKK1eDdFtTzh1KYQdCpXo2cJ1VpoJ3nCXpQpUI4tH67pkWhhqGMi/OSnId35G6VJanWJO1T4U4kTtwiYJ0o8Nnso3N0avigNzKyWAvP/j2TesgPdsXS9NviB5VMnsffezGk@ztAQ).

**6 bytes alternative provided by *@Grimy*:**

```
láÙg₂/
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/5/DCwzPTHzU16f//r@SSmaJQmV@qUFBaAqKLFPISc1MVMvMUSjJSFdzzk3JSSxTy0xTcMotSdRQ8EouKKu2VFIBSicXZqSkKyYk5uTmVegA) or [verify a few more test cases](https://tio.run/##HY69bcMwFIR7TXFREheB4YygFP4bIHWAJ@mZokXxyaQoh0YqFxkgXcrM4k28iEK7OuAO9@ETT6Xm6WuMRY7r9w/yIk7m8nf5Vdfz@XWaT1s5ogtVA9lhaBgrq4z2Dcj0DZU8oBb2ICg9soUfnLYKwXOR5UtdI0pAH4ZbOljqGNreORspTXon6lo7nmNLzt0k0kS@5RoVmc7ERfaemkPQVYvSydFiJ5/Yh673kJHdnWXoFJOHyt4en54/Zi/Fwz8).

Both programs output as decimal.

**Explanation:**

```python
l       # Convert the (implicit) input-string to lowercase
 AS     # Push the lowercase alphabet as character-list
   å    # Check for each if it's in the lowercase input-string
        # (1 if truthy; 0 if falsey)
    ÅA  # Get the arithmetic mean of this list
        # (and output the result implicitly)

l       # Convert the (implicit) input-string to lowercase
 á      # Only leave the letters in this lowercase string
  Ù     # Uniquify it
   g    # Get the amount of the unique lowercase letters by taking the length
    ₂/  # Divide this by 26
        # (and output the result implicitly)
```

Comment: @LuisMendo alternatively, `láêg₂/` is also a 6-byter.

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks (and you as well _Grimy_)! :)

Answer (score 7):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), <s>56</s> 49 bytes

```cs
a=>a.ToUpper().Distinct().Count(x=>x>64&x<91)/26f
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY29bsJAEIR7nmLkIrIlcJQoQorApggiKShBaWiO8x5ZsG@d@wl2Xt6YdKlmpJn5RvuZ9jxsotVLHxzb07SSeKyphCkGVZQq38m@bcmlWb5mH9jqMNo3iTakXVF25fzloVu@PmWPz3MzLCaTT8eBtmwpNWlySNZcoZeINoa7OljVENgifBHeZbwKEIMNO5riQznXY4VDgjFV/kIVtKqbus@TLFv8Z@/GyndkfcHRydXCSIdzbFoP@SH3x6/Vb49KTvfxcAM)

*-6 bytes thanks to [innat3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/86178/innat3)*

Comment: you can save 6 bytes by comparing the decimal values of the characters [50 bytes](https://tio.run/##VY0xb8IwFIR3fsUpA0okmoqqQqogYSgCho5UXViMY9MHiV94ttukfz4N3TrdSXf3nfYP2tOwjU6vfBBy51nF8VSbErYYVFGq/MDvbWskzfIN@UBOh9G@cnQh7YqyKxfP02m3eplnj08LOywnkw@hYN7ImdSmyTHZUIWeI9oY7ipwqjEgh/BpsOPxK4AttiRmhr0S6bHGMcGYKn81FbSqm7rPkyxb/mcfxsotkr7iJPztYLnDJTatB38Z@ePX6qdHxef7ePgF)  ([Character codes](https://www.dotnetperls.com/ascii-table))

Comment: @Innat3 49 bytes by changing the `&&` to `&`.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen ~2 mins off getting the -1 byte credit, already did that and was editing

Comment: @ExpiredData Np, it was an obvious golf. Was mainly directing it to Innat :)

Answer (score 7):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), <s>19</s> 15 bytes

**Solution:**

```
1%26%+/26>?97!_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/31DVyExVW9/IzM7e0lwxXilGySUzRaEyv1ShoLQERBcp5CXmpipk5imUZKQquOcn5aSWKOSnKbhlFqXqKHgkFhVV2scoKQDlEouzU1MUkhNzcnMq9ZT@/wcA)

**Explanation:**

Convert input to lowercase, modulo 97 ("a-z" is 97-122 in ASCII, modulo 97 gives 0-25), take unique, sum up results that are lower than 26, and convert to the percentage of 26.

```
1%26%+/26>?97!_ / the solution
              _ / lowercase
           97!  / modulo (!) 97
          ?     / distinct
       26>      / is 26 greater than this?
     +/         / sum (+) over (/)
  26%           / 26 divided by ...
1%              / 1 divided by ...
```

**Notes:**

- **-1 bytes** thanks to ngn, `1-%[;26]` => `1-1%26%`
- **-3 bytes** inspired by ngn `#(!26)^` => `+/26>?`

Comment: I'm looking forward to the explanation! I have no idea what that `97` is doing here

Comment: Another [19 bytes alternative](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/XzXa2sgsVls/My9aEciwNFeMV4pRcslMUajML1UoKC0B0UUKeYm5qQqZeQolGakK7vlJOaklCvlpCm6ZRak6Ch6JRUWV9jFKCkC5xOLs1BSF5MSc3JxKPaX//wE)

Comment: `%[;26]` -> `1%26%`

Comment: [`1%26%#?(26>)#97!_`](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/31DVyExV2V7DyMxOU9nSXDFeKUbJJTNFoTK/VKGgtAREFynkJeamKmTmKZRkpCq45yflpJYo5KcpuGUWpeooeCQWFVXaxygpAOUSi7NTUxSSE3Nycyr1lP7/BwA)

Comment: Great work as always, on mobile so will update my post when I'm online!

Comment: [`1%26%+/26>?97!_`](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/31DVyExVW9/IzM7e0lwxXilGySUzRaEyv1ShoLQERBcp5CXmpipk5imUZKQquOcn5aSWKOSnKbhlFqXqKHgkFhVV2scoKQDlEouzU1MUkhNzcnMq9ZT@/wcA) for 15

Comment: @streetster very nice

Answer (score 6):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 10 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anonymous tacit prefix function. Returns decimal fraction.

```apl
26÷⍨∘≢⎕A∩⌈
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/38js8PZHvSsedcx41LnoUd9Ux0cdKx/1dPxPe9Q24VFvH1DE0/9RV/Oh9caP2iYCecFBzkAyxMMz@H@agrqSS2aKQmV@qUJBaQmILlLIS8xNVcjMUyjJSFVwz0/KSS1RyE9TcMssStVR8EgsKqq0V1IASiUWZ6emKCQn5uTmVOqpcwGNCgGKFpZmJmcrJBXll@cppOVXKGSV5hYUK@SXpRaBzctJrKpUSMlPB6t3UFZRjVPTslcE89QB)

`⌈` uppercase

`⎕A∩` intersection with the uppercase **A**lphabet

`≢` tally length

`∘` then

`26÷⍨` divide by twenty-six

Comment: `⌹∘≤⍨⎕A∊⌈`­­­­­

Comment: @ngn That's very clever, but completely different. Go ahead and post that yourself. I'll be happy insert the explanation if you want me to.

Comment: [done&explained](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/187207/alphabet-completion-rate/187301#187301)

Answer (score 6):

### Bash and Gnu utils (<strike>81</strike> <strike>78</strike> <strike>68</strike> <strike>60</strike> 42 bytes)

```
bc -l<<<`grep -io [a-z]|sort -fu|wc -l`/26
```

-8 bytes thanks to [@wastl](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78123/wastl)

-18 bytes thanks to [Nahuel](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/70745/nahuel-fouilleul) using some tricks I didn't know:

- `sort -f` and `grep -i` ignore case
- `sort -u` is a replacement for `| uniq`

Comment: [60 bytes](https://tio.run/##HclLCsIwFEbhrfwUBwpG0YFTEURdg7Ob5JYU017JA4lk77F1dD44mqJrjY0TrNYp4KKeIPWtM5Wxf/biLdShRgkJKtePgfKb/fFU9aLWuutgUSTjndPSgIlGxjAhOcZdtOcE6XEbAm/xoBDKucO8KL7YwpAffdn9AA): `echo $(tr A-Z a-z|tr -cd a-z|fold -1|sort -u|wc -l)/26|bc -l`

Comment: Right. The variable is a reminder after another attempt. Thanks!

Comment: [42 bytes](https://tio.run/##FcpBCsIwEEbhq/x0bRRcuAq4EfUCrorQSTu1wbRTJikS6d2jXb3F9xzFoRTXwgRrbfNSnmG8oCbzfa5RNMH0y/rZhuZwPJVSXXyHLAvmR9qqmGhk@AlpYNzEBU6QHlevvMOdVPO5wp8ovrlDS2EMef8D)

Comment: Can't "grep -io [a-z]" be shortened to "grep -o [A-z]" ?

Comment: @Gnudiff Assuming ASCII, that would also match all of [\^_`].

Answer (score 6):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>27</s> 24 bytes

*-3 bytes thanks to nwellnhof*

```perl6
*.uc.comb(/<:L>/).Set/26
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYy9DoIwGEV3nuKGgagxJXFg8AcXow5u@gKlfGilpVhatb58RZd7knOS25NVRdQBWYMN4ox5wYTR1SRfL09lPmVncvmiiKtEyY6GsmRZM87AQ0x3skYwHr13P1p0XBNkB3cjHEylyME02EtLcxy5tWGbYkx8aKmG4EqrwJLLaB5eihaVNa8OjXnj7nU/wDzJ/r8U/wTU5voF)

Comment: +1 Also, while this works just fine (and `.lc` would work too), from a "correctness" standpoint, `.fc` might be better (particularly if the challenge had non-English letters)

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 47 bytes

```r
function(x)mean(65:90%in%utf8ToInt(toupper(x)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYxND8EwHMbvPsWjjFVEXAgSmYN4uTtLamupbf1P17L58jM7PXnefrZR2KJR3sROkwkrnkthwuVis54H2gTeqdWFzsaFjnxRSNsuOG9UOGZ7naAmj8K7v1oYkUtoA/eQONItkw6kcNBWTnES1tYRQ1uJMpUJYpHlWT0b817LurTxy@s4xc3Sx0BRhafPixL0lrYDZuJbI6F7d2C7wTC4jiZRn3WW8eYH)

Converts to upper case then to ASCII code-points, and checks for values 65:90 corresponding to A:Z.

Comment: This fails when there are quotes in the input.

Comment: @C.Braun Not in my tests... For instance, the first test case on TIO includes quotes and gives the correct result. Could you give an example?

Comment: I do not quite understand what you have done in the header part on TIO, but running just the code above in an R interpreter does not work. You seem to be redefining `scan` to not split on quotation marks, like the default does?

Comment: @C.Braun Got it, thanks! I've explicitly made it into a function (at a cost of 3 bytes) and I think it's OK now.

Answer (score 6):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <strike>55</strike> 52 bytes

```powershell
($args|% *per|% t*y|sort|gu|?{$_-in65..90}).count/26
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FclBCsIwEADAryylUi0aRbDgqRdRfyGxXdvQNBs2CRKMb4/1NIex9EZ2I2qd87qUPLi0gtoiL/g6Jkfs0xBS@ykfO2WakxDnw3cjOgrG749NzrkqLqqHSAFs8H8ZjJwRlAE/ItzoqdEDveCqGLdwl8yxLWAp6SbsoZN61lFUPw)

First attempt, still trying random ideas

EDIT: @Veskah pointed out ToUpper saves a byte due to the number range, also removed extra `()` and a space

Expansion:
`($args|% ToUpper|% ToCharArray|sort|get-unique|where{$_-in 65..90}).count/26`

Changes string to all <strike>lower</strike>uppercase, expands to an array, sorts the elements and selects the unique letters (gu needs sorted input), keep only characters of ascii value <strike>97 to 122 (a to z)</strike> 65 to 90 (A to Z), count the total and divide by 26 for the decimal output

Comment: [Uppercase saves a byte](https://tio.run/##dctLCsIwFIXhuau4lEofaNSClY46EXUXEtu0DaZJuUmQYFx7rCOdOPrhHL5JPRjqgQkRQhpT7LVfQj5vc0zuvFZofG99/Yyvay7T6kDIriiyV0YaZaXZFOXi66a/rtwTUm1/WQghiY68BacsTNZ8iiDpyIBLMAODs7oJZkB1cOLIVnChiK6OYL6ovrMWGipG4UjyBg "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: oh, just noticed you have an extra space after -in.

Answer (score 4):

## Java 8, <s>62</s> 59 bytes

```java
s->s.map(c->c&95).distinct().filter(c->c%91>64).count()/26.
```

-3 bytes thanks to *@OlivierGrégoire*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jZFPbxMxEMXv/RSPhVa7tDEqaiu1iIQD0HJoL@VGW2nidbJOvPbisROWKp89TJZwRfXB/2b8fm/GC1rRaFEvt9oRM27J@ucDwPpk4oy0wd3uCNQhT52BLhfyQOVkneIUDbXqm0/3ww5cfZDczYFMnChZjTt4fMSWR2NWLXWlHo310eV5pWrLyXqdykrNrBPWEDq8PB1fnFVKh@wl9O79hdruJDthi9pedBVsjVaMlsK1fv7jEVT9dTkLcX8JxhW8WeNfznNxE9Zos24QZkiNwRc/d5YbkOsampokNRoGYW5XxgtskMlsJsXJIP6/UTwUn8VVH7KYTbs1wlNrpJED6zpI99KO/NVGc4IbirGfPBSQGPHS1NDkWterl7C@y6Of2eolpjGsvVT9C4vcdoywMnHgOfrdSz3zl8h9ev3m8Ono7eRVsan22fc9J9OqkJPqpA3J@ZKPiysUx17pkpVuKHJZVfsP32z/AA)

**Explanation:**

```java
s->                     // Method with IntStream as parameter and double return-type
  s.map(c->c&95)        //  Convert all letters to uppercase
   .distinct()          //  Uniquify it
   .filter(c->c%91>64)  //  Only leave letters (unicode value range [65,90])
   .count()             //  Count the amount of unique letters left
    /26.                //  Divide it by 26.0
```

Comment: [59 bytes](https://tio.run/##jZFPbxMxEMXv/RSPhVa7tDEqaiu1iIQD0HJoL@VGW2nidbJOvPbisROWKp89TJZwRfXB/2b8fm/GC1rRaFEvt9oRM27J@ucDwPpk4oy0wd3uCNQhT52BLhfyQOVkneIUDbXqm0/3ww5cfZDczYFMnChZjTt4fMSWR2NWLXWlHo310eV5pWrLyXqdykrNrBPWEDq8PB1fnFVKh@wl9O79hdruJDthi9pedBVsjVaMlsK1fv7jEVT9dTkLcX8JxhW8WeNfznNxE9Zos24QZkiNwRc/d5YbkOsampokNRoGYW5XxgtskMlsJsXJIP6/UTwUn8VVH7KYTbs1wlNrpJED6zpI99KO/NVGc4IbirGfPBSQGPHS1NDkWterl7C@y6Of2eolpjGsvVT9C4vcdoywMnHgOfrdSz3zl8h9ev3m8Ono7eRVsan22fc9J9OqkJPqpA3J@ZKPiysUx17pkpVuKHJZVfsP32z/AA)

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Thanks! I always forget about `c&95` in combination with `c%91>64` for some reason. I think you've already suggested that golf a few times before to me.

Comment: Yes, I already suggested those, but that's OK, no worries ;-)

Comment: Way longer, but more fun: `s->{int r=0,b=0;for(var c:s)if((c&95)%91>64&&b<(b|=1<<c))r++;return r/26.;}` (75 bytes)

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 45 bytes

```
T`Llp`ll_
+`(.)(.*\1)
$2
.
100$*
^
13$*
.{26}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY49T8MwGIR3/4qjpCgNyGqKxJoOQDswdkQlTvI2cevYwR8tAfHbg@n0SHe6R2fJSy2mebopp135poZSqQ92X6Z8kfLsPV@wZMU4y5fLJGN7lj9G8J/V0@80bc0Ffag7mAN8R3jRrZKug1BDJyryaAw5CLTyTBrOW6lbBEcFmz3LBqMJGIL/p4UWPUHqq2djKhXX0foqLT1gK6wdixliJdyJGtRC9WrkbBeTzyDrEyprLhoH84Vj6AcHcyZ7dSnxPcYfLVvfJvP9XVbc/AE) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
T`Llp`ll_
```

Lowercase letters and delete punctuation.

```
+`(.)(.*\1)
$2
```

Deduplicate.

```
.
100$*
```

Multiply by 100.

```
^
13$*
```

Add 13.

```
.{26}
```

Integer divide by 26 and convert to decimal.

Comment: I think retina is the only language here using percentages for the output!

Comment: Oh, nice trick with adding unary 13 before dividing! Why didn't I think of that.. >.> It would make [my answer 44 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/187218/52210). I'll still leave my previous version, though.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Probably because Retina is also the only language from the ones posted thus far which doesn't have decimal division available. Only (unary) integer-division is possible.

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 8 bytes

```apl
⌹∘≤⍨⎕A∊⌈
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn//1HPzkcdMx51LnnUu@JR31THRx1dj3o6/qc9apvwqLcPKOLp/6ir@dB640dtE4G84CBnIBni4Rn8P01BXcklM0WhMr9UoaC0BEQXKeQl5qYqZOYplGSkKrjnJ@Wklijkpym4ZRal6ih4JBYVVdorKQClEouzU1MUkhNzcnMq9dS5gEaFAEULSzOTsxWSivLL8xTS8isUskpzC4oV8stSi8Dm5SRWVSqk5KeD1Tsoq6jGqWnZK4J56gA)

loosely based on [Adám's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/187211/24908)

`⌈` uppercase

`⎕A∊` boolean (0 or 1) vector of length 26 indicating which letters of the English **A**lphabet are in the string

`⌹∘≤⍨` arithmetic mean, i.e. matrix division of the argument and an all-1 vector of the same length

Answer (score 3):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 19 bytes

```
1%26%26-#(!26)^97!_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P83KUNXIDIh0lTUUjcw04yzNFeP/pykoxSi5ZKYoVOaXKhSUloDoIoW8xNxUhcw8hZKMVAX3/KSc1BKF/DQFt8yiVB0Fj8Siokr7GCUFoFxicXZqikJyYk5uTqWeEtd/AA)

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 30 bytes

```
26%~26-u:@(97+i.26)#@-.tolower
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYzBCoJAGAbvPsWHEVukS3gwEiKhqA6dohdYda2t1d9Wt7JDr27WocMwh4G5dC5nORYRGDxMEfX4HKvDftMF4fAdhL6N4tF8NlE8CMeD2OcNaXpI040dODI9E3Iwd60ytGRR2eZrg1IUEqpEc5bYUqJlA8qxUUZ62Alj2qWLPon6KjOkQhe65ez/O/bpZlV6RWLoUSKnJy62qGrQXZrfVItXi4xOrPsA)

Comment: `32!` is too broad - it makes the rest of the expression treat some punctuation chars as letters, for instance [try adding `:`](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P81Kw1DVyExTy8hMV1nDUFsRyI4zNlL8n6agZBWj5JKZolCZX6pQUFoCoosU8hJzUxUy8xRKMlIV3POTclJLFPLTFNwyi1J1FDwSi4oq7WOUFIByicXZqSkKyYk5uTmVekpc/wE) in the example input

Comment: @ngn I didn't test with punctuation at first. Thanks for reminding me.!

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>57</s> <s>46</s> 35 bytes

```
.
$L
[^a-z]

D`.
.
100*
^
13*
_{26}
```

-11 bytes taking inspiration from [*@Neil*'s trick of adding unary 13 before dividing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/187223/52210).
Another -11 bytes thanks to *@Neil* directly.
Rounds (correctly) to a whole integer.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##HY5NT8JAGITv768YEYxptGlBUU/1A4WDR2/Gwtt2aVe2u7jbBYvxt9fKaZKZPE/GikZqjrvR@XzVhTR8pfeULw8fRLNVSCHFURRQSvEkoOXPePrbdQuzR@3zCmaNphJ41qWSrgKrbcWZaFAY4cAo5U5ouMZKXcI7kdBgJgu0xmPrm/@00FwLSH30zE2merq3vkgrLrBga9tkgH5itxEFcla1akN665svL/MNMmv2GmvzjU9fbx3MTtijS/Gh7X@UdH86HKVnQXJCnOXF0@MDxePJ1fX05vYuWvIf)

**<s>57</s> <s>46</s> 40 bytes version which works with decimal output:**

```
.
$L
[^a-z]

D`.
.
1000*
C`_{26}
-1`\B
.
```

Same -11 bytes as well as an additional -6 bytes thanks to *@Neil*.

Outputs with one ***truncated***<sup>*†*</sup> decimal after the comma (<sup>*†*</sup> i.e. \$0.1538\$ (\$\frac{4}{26}\$) is output as `15.3` instead of `15.4`). This is done by calculating \$\lfloor{\frac{1000 × \text{unique_letters}}{26}\rfloor}\$ and then inserting the decimal dot manually.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##HY5NT8JAFEX371c8EYwhMmlRUVdVQGHh0p0KfW2HdmQ6U@cDKMbfXkdWN7k35@Qa7oSiuBtcLtKOQf8V3lc0On4CzFMGDOIoioYwS9c/48kvjOL0Ywqs65Z6j7XPK9QbdBXHZ1VKYSsk2VSUcYeF5hYJS7HjCq0zQpXoLU@gNxcFttpj491/GlRUcxTq5FnoTAY6WF@E4Ve4JGPapIdhIrvlBeYka9kyeAvNtxf5FjOj9wo3@oBfvm4s6h03J5ekYxt@lPB43h@sLobJGVCWF7PpE8Tj65vbyd39Q7SmPw)

**Explanation:**

Convert all letters to lowercase:

```
.
$L
```

Remove all non-letters:

```
[^a-z]
```

Uniquify all letters:

```
D`.
```

Replace every unique letter with 1000 underscores:

```
.
1000*
```

Count the amount of times 26 adjacent underscores fit into it:

```
C`_{26}
```

Insert a dot at the correct place:

```
-1`\B
.
```

Comment: The `.*` could just be `.` for a 1 byte saving, but you can save another 10 bytes by using `D`eduplicate instead of doing it manually!

Comment: @Neil Ah, didn't knew about the `D`-builtin, thanks! And not sure why I used `.*` instead of `.`.. Thanks for -11 bytes in both versions! :)

Comment: FYI I had a slightly different approach for the same byte count: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY5NT8JAFEX371c8sRDTmKYFRF3VDxQWLk3cEMprZ2hHpjN1pgMW8bfXkdVN7s05uYa3QlHSD68Wm371cVqxUwYwDzYRBG8QQRLHIawhmYSQ/Yxnv32/1AesXVGh3mJbcXxRpRS2QpJNRTlvkWlukbAUe67QtkaoEp3lKQzmgmGnHTau/U@DimqOQp09C51LT3vrqzD8GpdkTJcO0E9kd5xhQbKWXQTvvvlyothhbvRB4VZ/46erG4t6z83ZJenY@R8lPFwGw/UoTC@A8oI9Pz1CMp5Mb2a3d/dxRn8 "Retina – Try It Online")

Comment: For the decimal version I found that ``-1`\B`` matches the desired insertion position directly.

Comment: @Neil Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 11 bytes

```
Ｉ∕ＬΦβ№↧θι²⁶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYoxEoIwEAB7X3FDlcxECwsbCwsYtKDwC0c45caQ6HHg8PoYm91i148oPmHI@S4c1dQ4q2l45YFMR/Gpo2k5KInpHdRpKUuXviQeZzIf64CtLTyeis45Vw0PsKUF3ov@LRBxIuAIOhJcUx9IIT2gZSEHNxTZLhWUhPOLBvAYprAddnm/hh8) Link is to verbose version of code. Output is as a decimal (or `1` for pangrams). Explanation:

```
  Ｌ         Length of
    β       Lowercase alphabet
   Φ        Filtered on
     №      Count of
        ι   Current letter in
      ↧     Lowercased
       θ    Input
 ∕          Divided by
         ²⁶ Literal 26
Ｉ           Cast to string
            Implicitly printed
```

Answer (score 3):

### Batch, 197 bytes

```
@set/ps=
@set s=%s:"=%
@set n=13
@for %%c in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z)do @call set t="%%s:%%c=%%"&call:c
@cmd/cset/an/26
@exit/b
:c
@if not "%s%"==%t% set/an+=100
```

Takes input on STDIN and outputs a rounded percentage. Explanation:

```
@set/ps=
```

Input the string.

```
@set s=%s:"=%
```

Strip quotes, because they're a headache to deal with in Batch.

```
@set n=13
```

Start with half a letter for rounding purposes.

```
@for %%c in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z)do @call set t="%%s:%%c=%%"&call:c
```

Delete each letter in turn from the string. Invoke the subroutine to check whether anything changed, because of the way Batch parses variables.

```
@cmd/cset/an/26
```

Calculate the result as a percentage.

```
@exit/b
:c
```

Start of subroutine.

```
@if not "%s%"=="%t%" set/an+=100
```

If deleting a letter changed the string then increment the letter count.

Answer (score 3):

## [Pepe](https://github.com/Soaku/Pepe), <s>155</s> 138 bytes

```
rEeEeeeeeEREeEeEEeEeREERrEEEEErEEEeReeReRrEeeEeeeeerEEEEREEeRERrErEErerREEEEEeREEeeRrEreerererEEEEeeerERrEeeeREEEERREeeeEEeEerRrEEEEeereEE
```

[Try it online!](https://soaku.github.io/Pepe/#!aa!bpF--i!o/.-!8g!qT&-_E$@&1!l-_*$$Ds_-!c!r-!85@-_wM) Output is in decimal form.

**Explanation:**

```c
rEeEeeeeeE REeEeEEeEe # Push 65 -> (r), 90 -> (R)
REE # Create loop labeled 90 // creates [65,66,...,89,90]
  RrEEEEE # Increment (R flag: preserve the number) in (r)
  rEEEe # ...then move the pointer to the last
Ree # Do this while (r) != 90

Re # Pop 90 -> (R)
RrEeeEeeeee rEEEE # Push 32 and go to first item -> (r)
REEe # Push input -> (R)
RE RrE # Push 0 on both stacks, (r) prepend 0
rEE # Create loop labeled 0 // makes input minus 32, so the
    # lowercase can be accepted, since of rEEEEeee (below)
  re # Pop 0 -> (r)
  rREEEEEe REEee # Push item of (R) minus 32, then go to next item 
  RrE # Push 0 -> (R)
ree # Do while (R) != 0

rere # Pop 0 & 32 -> (r)
rEEEEeee # Remove items from (r) that don't occur in (R)
         # Remove everything from (r) except the unique letters
rE # Push 0 -> (r)
RrEeee # Push reverse pointer pos -> (r)
REEEE # Move pointer to first position -> (R)
RREeeeEEeEe # Push 26 -> (R)
rRrEEEEee reEE # Divide it and output it
```

Comment: Since Pepe is only a 4 command language really it's like 34.5 bytes if you encoded it as 2 bits per r e R E?

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 34 bytes

```julia
s->sum('a':'z'.∈lowercase(s))/26
```

Uses the [vectorized](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/mathematical-operations/#man-dot-operators-1) version of the ∈ operator, checking containment in the string for all characters in the range from a to z. Then sums over the resulting BitArray and divides by total number of possible letters.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYxLDoIwFEXnruKJH8D4iQ4cmCgOjLoAxyZPKFooLb5S@azAdboRrM6Md3KT@zmJERznVRuvWz3ZaJN5Lrort3Gnr@dTqJJRiJp52vdni2WbE5eFkF7sEZaO1Y5HUCsDuSk@TiAxY8AlFDcGB3URrAAVw54TG8MRierAAVuhTlkEIYpM1FPL8f3OL/tkR3fDwxQupEoJsaogMVmuQT0YffECmxoidf0//yfbXn9wHo6Crq3aNw)

Comment: Welcome and great first answer!

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
ŒuØAe€Æm
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opNLDMxxTHzWtOdyW@///fyWXzBSFyvxShYLSEhBdpJCXmJuqkJmnUJKRquCen5STWqKQn6bgllmUqqPgkVhUVGmvpACUSizOTk1RSE7Myc2p1AMA)

#### Explanation

```
Œu       | Convert to upper case
  ØAe€   | Check whether each capital letter is present, returning a list of 26 0s and 1s
      Æm | Mean
```

Answer (score 2):

## C, 96 bytes

```C
float f(char*s){int i=66,l[256]={};for(;*s;)l[1+*s++&~32]=1;for(;i<92;*l+=l[i++]);return*l/26.;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY3RToMwFIbv9xRHdAttcWYYSUwl88KoD@AdYNKVdqsrLRZQEdmrI5vXcm7@5Hx//o9fbjkfBqktq0H6fMccrlCnTA0qjqJAJ@FNlMVdT6V1PsUVRTpZEVwRsjhch1m8@gPq7jakWJNYJ4qQDFEn6sYZrK/CaEn74ThYMGV8NOtmMF7pxpf0vblMjReMai/1HlQOrW2gbOpjOjCsEKAM1DsBT3ajRQ1WwqNyIoBn5ly7Tj0YGav2IgfOdKHbpYcQ/UfxMnbfG8X3sHH204C0X/DWFGUF9kO4k0az7xZyu51YuT@/mL8u8PpsotP99IcJfEL98As)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-MList::Util=uniq -p`, 24 bytes

```perl
$_=uniq(lc=~/[a-z]/g)/26
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hc2xCgIxDADQX8ngoEMpCDocHE6Cgzc6iUg9YxuoTb2kCg5@uhF8P/AqTnllNjv3rdBjnsf@44/BvU8@LvxybbbjF9zbmIBvoAlhW2ImSRByTeGCCldGgQCRnlhAdKISoQluvlyVuIi5YU@iXXdQyv/FXP0B)

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
░║üy$}╙+C
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=b0ba8179247dd32b43&i=%22Did+you+put+your+name+in+the+Goblet+of+Fire,+Harry%3F%22+he+asked+calmly.%0AThe+quick+brown+fox+jumps+over+the+lazy+dog%0A%21%40%23%24%25%5E%26*%28%29%0A%22%22&a=1&m=2)

Comment: You can take a byte off the unpacked version by dropping `u` and using `|b`, but the savings disappear under packing. I might have an 8-byter, but the online interpreter is being weird and buggy.

Comment: @Khuldraesethna'Barya: Nice find.  

I think the bug is probably an array mutation.  I'm seeing some of that behavior now.  Working on a minimal repro...

Comment: [Here's a repro](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=VaP%0A%22abcdef%22Va%7Cbd%0AVaP&i=&a=1) of the problem I guess you're having with `|b`.  It incorrectly mutates its operand rather than making a copy.  I've created a github issue for the bug.  https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/issues/29

As a workaround, `|b` will work correctly the first time.  After that, you may have to reload the page.  

If you found a different bug, if you can provide a reproduction, I'll probably be able to fix it.

Comment: [Stax 1.1.4, 8 bytes.](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=845191c772084fa4&i=%22Did+you+put+your+name+in+the+Goblet+of+Fire,+Harry%3F%22+he+asked+calmly.) Instructions: unpack, insert `v` at the start, insert `|b` after `Va`, run, remove the first `v`, remove `|b`, repack.

Yep, that's the bug I found.

Comment: @Khuldraesethna'Barya: I've released 1.1.5, and I believe this bug is fixed now.  You can let me know if you still have trouble.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 45 bytes

```javascript
s=>~-s.match(/$|([a-z])(?!.*\1)/ig).length/26
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xcy9CsIwFEDh3ae4gmAitEUHF6lOgg/gpg4x3ibRNLf2pvUH8dVrdXQ98J2zahXr2lUxCXTCrsg7zpfvhNNSRW1FNnqJnUqeBylWw3Syn8rMGZl6DCbabDbvNAUmj6knIwox3tANykZboAKiRVgH4x1bUL6y6ogRToQMCoxrMQDH2gUDDeNqLOXg77Xt/bVx@gLHmm4BCrrDuSkrBmqx/u29ej76pen14p9/W/cB)

---

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 47 bytes

```javascript
s=>(s.match(/([a-z])(?!.*\1)/ig)||[]).length/26
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcyxDoIwEIDh3ac4J1sTITq4GHUy8QHclKGWo62WHnIFlfjuiI6sf/L9N9Uq1rWr4iJQjn2x7Xm7E5yUKmorUnFWiy6TYj9N5pelTJ2Rn885k4nHYKJNV@teU2DymHgyohCzIz2hbLQFKiBahEMw3rEF5SurrhghJ2RQYFyLATjWLhhoGPczKSej12nwj8bpO1xregYo6AW3pqwYqMX6v/eqew9LM@jNmP9a/wU)

Answer (score 2):

## Swift 5.9, <s>105</s> <s>100</s> 89 bytes

```swift
let p={Float((65...90).filter(($0+"").uppercased().map(\.asciiValue).contains).count)/26}
```

Using `Float` instead of `Double` saved a byte.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 9 bytes

```
;CoU Ê/26
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=O0NvVSDKLzI2&input=IkhvdyBtdWNoIG9mIHRoZSBFbmdsaXNoIGFscGhhYmV0IGRvZXMgYSBnaXZlbiBzdHJpbmcgdXNlPyI)

```
;CoU Ê/26     :Implicit input of string U
;C            :Lowercase alphabet
  oU          :Remove the characters not included in U, case insensitive
     Ê        :Length
      /26     :Divide by 26
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 57 bytes

```python
lambda i:len(set(o for o in i.lower()if o.isalpha()))/26.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rY9NSwMxEIbv/orX@pFEZYUeeijYehD1B3gsQrabuLHZTJxkrfHPr1sRhXoSPA3MzPPMO7HklsJ0sFerweuubjTc3Jsgk8mSYIlBcAGu8rQ1LJWzoMol7WOrpVLqcjqrhsguZIjJjWtQqEfs864ygu7MDs@twR3V3mSQxa1jc4F7zVyWE4wjnTamwVr7zpcKiwUEzpEySyv/SSqUGpViFcTBV9iHceWld@sNaqZtGF99w3PfxQR6Nfwp9/q9oKGnvUR/IH@fvT46Pnk8PVse7km/@z/I8AE)

A bit longer than the [Python 3 answer from ArBo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/187210/56555) but posted as a different approach in Python 2 anyway.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-n`, <s>38</s> 34 bytes

-4 bytes from @historcrat!

```ruby
p (?A..?Z).count{|c|~/#{c}/i}/26.0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYzLDgExGEb3nuIzLkHoiIXtkAgewMpC0ukUZab/6LSo26Ory@ok5yTHuNSHUKKTTBlL1l0myGl7f4jHK27cxTNWz3g0ZsMQopnK4MmhdPZHA80LCaVh9xILSnNpQVvMlZF9LLkxPonwTbw6ygyC50XuWW31NSenxBGpoYvGlq44uKKsQGdp/q@c3zwy2tWiSaPZ2rR7ST16U2kV6SoM9Ac)

Comment: @histocrat you are correct

Answer (score 1):

## C, 95 bytes

```
f(char*s){int a[256]={},z;while(*s)a[*s++|32]=1;for(z=97;z<'z';*a+=a[z++]);return(*a*100)/26;}
```

(note: rounds down)

#### Alternate decimal-returning version (95 bytes):

```
float f(char*s){int a[256]={},z;while(*s&&a[*s++|32]=1);for(z=97;z<'z';*a+=a[z++]);return*a/26.;}
```

This borrows some from @Steadybox' answer.

Comment: Welcome! Good first answer. It might be helpful for people reading your answer if you provide a short explanation of your code or an ungolfed version. It may also be helpful to provide a link to an online interpreter with your runnable code (see some other answers for examples). Many use TIO, and here's the [gcc interpreter](https://tio.run/#c-gcc)

Answer (score 1):

## [K4](http://kx.com/download), <s>14</s> 13 bytes

**Solution:**

```
avg .Q.a in _
```

**Explanation:**

Rather <s>stolen from</s> *inspired by* [Luis Mendo's Octave solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/187212/69200)...

```
avg .Q.a in _ / the solution
            _ / lowercase the input
         in   / 'in' function
    .Q.a      / "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
avg           / average (mean)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>51</s> 49 bytes

*51 -> 49 bytes, thanks to alexz02*

```python
lambda s:len({*filter(str.isalpha,s.lower())})/26
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FclBCsIwEEDRqwzdNJESQcGFGzeiXmNqpjQ4TcJkigTx7LGuPryfq84pHluWENWYxriMHqGcmaL57KbASmKKigsFOc84FMfpvZm1X7s/nJo1fXcNHmpaIa/6r0DEhSBE0JngnkYmhTTBLQgN8ECReulgW1he5OGJvHB1vbXtBw)

Comment: 49 bytes
`lambda s:len({*filter(str.isalpha,s.lower())})/26`

Comment: @alexz02 Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax 1.1.4 online interpreter](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/releases/tag/v1.1.4), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax), noncompeting

```
äQæ╟r◘Oñ
```

[Run and debug it at staxlang.xyz!](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=845191c772084fa4&i=%22Did+you+put+your+name+in+the+Goblet+of+Fire,+Harry%3F%22+he+asked+calmly.)

#### Unpacked (9 bytes) and explanation:

```
Va%26!/vN
Va           Push the lowercase alphabet
  %          Length...?! Shouldn't this always be 26?
   26!       Push 26.0
      /      Divide
       vN    Subtract from one (decrement and negate)
```

That shouldn't work. Looking at it, you would expect an output of 0 always. Heck, it doesn't even take input! There's a [bug](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/issues/29) in the online interpreter, however, which I have exploited for this answer.

Now, I've marked this answer noncompeting for a reason. As far as I can tell, this exploit requires some human interaction to set up. Here's what you gotta do:

- Put your input in the input field
- Unpack
- Insert `v` at the start of the code and `|b` immediately after `Va`
- Run
- Remove the characters you added to the code
- Repack

Now you have an 8-byte program that will give the correct output each time you run it! At least until you change the input field or reload the page.

#### What in the seven hells is going on:

```
Va%26!/vN
Va           Push the lowercase alphabet, EXCLUDING characters that existed in the input field in either case any time the vVa|b version was run
  %26!/vN    Everything else works as expected
```

That little bug handles case checking and filtering for free, at the expense of leaving me with the wrong set of letters (wasting two bytes on the `vN`). I think this can be improved rather easily, but I'm at work right now.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 52 bytes

```hs
f s=sum[1|n<-[0..25],or[elem([c..]!!n)s|c<-"aA"]]/26
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY7PSgMxHIRfZRo8KOxGLeipRYRSfQBvaQ6/ZpM2Nv9MNupKn9249TQw3/AxRyon7VxrBmVdqhf357DqxR3nywfZxSy00/5aKM7lYhFuylmtekbPTMrb5WPzZAPWSNmGEVfwlGAg2I5t7IApVqQ6XjIjkNeYx@NR4yXunR4RDbY26w6vlPP0tGOY2eXOAEXOu4mzDuxtLj@qVSfsc/wKMPEb79Wngvip87/P0c@EIR6YbL/KODqU1quU/gA)

Avoids case conversion (which base Haskell lacks) and ASCII-code conversions (which are lengthy) in favor of writing `[c..`] to enumerate characters. For example, `['A'..]` is a very long list that starts with `ABCDEFGHI...`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ohm v2](https://github.com/nickbclifford/Ohm), 7 bytes

```
ÁαA}εÆm
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8/INfr//3DjuY2Otee2Hm7L/f9fKUbJJTNFoTK/VKGgtAREFynkJeamKmTmKZRkpCq45yflpJYo5KcpuGUWpeooeCQWFVXaxygpAOUSi7NTUxSSE3Nycyr1lAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 9 bytes

```
cl@rw0G26
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fcm9CoAgFAbQV/lwjoiG1hqieg3TG0r@xE0Jn95qOsO5SjK1Kjfx0639UKuYrUaJGVdOv4wgPcEGJENY4@4oIR5YLFODTTKXUeAreZ@koaTzrrQv)

```
c      26 # Float division by 26 (alternative: replace 26 by lG)
 l        #   Length of
  @       #     intersection of
   r 0    #       lowercase
    w     #         input
      G   #       and the lowercase alphabet
```

Answer (score 1):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) -R, 36 + 3 = 39 bytes

```
1/length*([scan("[a-zA-Z]")]|length)
```

The `-R` flag is required, otherwise stdin needs to be a quoted string.

Comment: Does this work? For instance, it counts all occurrences, including duplicates, so the quick brown fox ends up having less than 100%. See the tests on [TIO](https://tio.run/##JYzdCoIwGEDvfYqv9YNKFj2BBVFdR1eJwdSp07lP56yUnr1ldXXgHDhFY8xmLZjMdO7aQRtTaZOAesPOu4bECV//5BhD9jyBHjuoO/2lAkkrBlyCzhkcMRJMA6Zw4Iot4USV6n0CY6JtyRKIqahEv7Iuo2k6HpcQKXxISPEJRVfVLeCdqd9L0KGHBDOLbKez@W3h@hNiEfLGWnOUrfHOHw).

Answer (score 1):

## [Emacs Lisp](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/eintr.html), 91 bytes

```lisp
(lambda(a)(load"cl")(/(count-if(lambda(x)(< ?` x ?z))(remove-duplicates(downcase a)))26.0))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ncy7DgIhEIXh3qeYUJgZklVjYWVi7QPYOwtsRGFBLrrx5RELu5P8J5/xrPLgbI6tYUx2LisAnOqs2DnoG9CxHzUjE7rAWignCLeoQp3LYKd/XgiPcLrCAqcPESbjw8sMukZnFReTUYd3R7MBJqL9YbMj@vECys3As1r1gDH1D0xhgXv1MUMXEsi1RHmReJaCqLUv)

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), <s>210</s> 196 bytes

```go
import(."strings";U"unicode")
func f(s string)float64{s=Map(func(r rune)rune{if!U.IsLetter(r){r=-1};return r},ToLower(s))
m:=make(map[rune]int)
for _,r:=range s{m[r]++}
return float64(len(m))/26.}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XY_LTgIxFIb38xTHekkrMEZjiIFMcGG8JJi4gBVBKUNnrEzb8bQVccKTuCEmPoR74zv4Ns4AC8OmJ-2X8_f73z9Ss_zKeTzlqQDFpQ6kyg26kCTKkU_vksbZ7_f6jYbEOpQ6taTdJ17L2EwEYUHidQwJtbCmLMkMd83Twka3PKcVpQjotWDVUchkpx_e2K5wTiBFVmDUOF60UTiPGnBR75mumZXIMhaoVqT4VFDF80G1PZTalT8ahIc6tiLkuvS2hRrgsFZbBJuQjQHNhKaKsaOTZrjYdPlZ2VZNKYMiuCuNXaZpQkfkQk5gbjzk3lUTQXMlQGpwjwKuzDgTDkwClxJFHa454rxDoETcTsUEYp6pbB6OSul_ob2SP3sZT2GMZlaamVd48iq3YF4ErpIz_jaHiUm3Nsn57t7-_cFhZ2cLVNdNm-VyPf8A)

Returns a float in `[0,1]`.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 72 bytes

```c
i;j;f(char*s){for(i=j=0;i++<26;)j+=index(s,i+64)!=index(s,i+96);j/=.26;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYzfToMwFMbv9xRn6Ew7cC7GkJBK5oVRH8C7qUlXWjgMWjwtbrj47Mi88urL9/v@qOtSqXFEUQvDVCVp6fnJOGKY1/laYBzf36aC13GOttBH5hOM0zs@/2ezlIv6Jl9NvZ/xfAF@m2XZu2glWsZPhwobzUodPPOcd4Q2GBYtijcbJeaMBOnQk4X1tI8esYDB9dD14awEVrYa0EKoNDy7XaMDOANPSDqBF0k0bCKYIun3ugAlm7YZVrPXiXz2qPawI3ewYNwR6r7tPLgvTX9fjfweoHDl7OHicvFxtdzMo18)

-9B from c--

## x86 opcode, 35 bytes

```c
00000180: 575e 31ff ac2c 4172 030f abc7 0441 75f4  W^1..,Ar.....Au.
00000190: c1e7 06f3 0fb8 c750 df04 2458 6a1a de34  .......P..$Xj..4
000001a0: 2458 c3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVRhb9MwEP3uX3F0DK1Tk3Td6FALG0MTMAmExCb4sJTIsZ3Eq2NntrOlQ/z2YicpExJjy4fkbL/37nz3lBSbYs1IoWCwvky5NTA9WCA0hxNRFThlFogqK8EsVxI0tswdFdZWZhZFRFGWK5GFxmKyZA0psMxZ6AjRdc2Mp5ho79XhZHwY4V4uuJcLWjmnJ7EpARMd@m@gfKQgyJjIpgcIGUba5KFljUXgnlyoFAvImU0c1isIJXOgqk4F22zvuGr0Lhirhw6QKSHUrYFmegDnK/MNTt6duW0uq9rC19OzGchaiIAywUtuGfU8LnMHUbX1mPOL8QwqpgmTFufMMV033G3hcjyCvQXqs87aAqvaFKAp7xaqAm26uFEaGOUj/0KhUKrqCEJRk7aRqVPAYgTTl@3yKoXQLHnVLlI3nY6NG9Rud2xM6V8ceQetNkKhWnYQU4iOOt3URKT1Ol0p90U7Zb/IuKBwqzSFS22qxf1F@vMWPJn2WMpvHgK3C80sQkzSpMR6yXSSKZ0IJnNbJFwmKr2idVklruRlgm0i6zJlfSelqtYDOOrN4URap6ItLomoKYPXxlKuwuIIoSiCnBAoMZchgd5EqnQBBN@xEBB82XcCjWVaPmKYOULctcdL7dwoTofws@uixZYT8ECP27tcwBuIB3EcD045hZWqwXvFfbUzddm6xBYMPiiXx4LK4D3XbAQfsdarY08Dd4rN0hmOYFGKVRgP5v9KNelTXTj8dc3JElKtbqXzdQNXrnkG1A3TbTKB71buavkDSvu90tut59s/XuweP/O4bmTO8TbbiQfbn7I4lvFg9Kc1/rLD4fwJsMnTYPsb2MYftRvKeI5@ITftboQI/fe/8Pisw6hsfw@9vyA4heCzK4qJjoGahnbR@jc)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3), 6 bytes

```
ʀuȦL₂÷
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyIiLCIiLCLKgHXIpkzigoLDtyIsIiIsIlwiXCJEaWQgeW91IHB1dCB5b3VyIG5hbWUgaW4gdGhlIEdvYmxldCBvZiBGaXJlLCBIYXJyeT9cIiBoZSBhc2tlZCBjYWxtbHkuXCIiLCIzLjQuMiJd)

length of unique lowercase letters divided by 26

Answer (score 1):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org) <sup>[SBCS](http://tinyurl.com/Uiua-SBCS-Feb-17)</sup>, 9 bytes

```
÷26⧻◴▽±.⌵
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_10_0-dev_1__RiDihpAgw7cyNuKnu-KXtOKWvcKxLuKMtQoKRiAiXCJEaWQgeW91IHB1dCB5b3VyIG5hbWUgaW4gdGhlIEdvYmxldCBvZiBGaXJlLCBIYXJyeT9cIiBoZSBhc2tlZCBjYWxtbHkuIgpGICJUaGUgcXVpY2sgYnJvd24gZm94IGp1bXBzIG92ZXIgdGhlIGxhenkgZG9nIgpGICJAIyQlXiYqPyEiCkYgIiIK)

```
÷26⧻◴▽±.⌵
        ⌵  # uppercase
       .   # duplicate
      ±    # mask of cases (-1 for lower, 1 for upper, 0 for neither)
     ▽     # keep (only the letters)
    ◴      # remove duplicates
   ⧻       # length
÷26        # divided by 26
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>61</s> <s>54</s> 51 bytes

```
s=>new Set(s.toLowerCase().match(/[a-z]/g)).size/26
```

Comment: [57 bytes](https://tio.run/##XY4xT8MwEIV3fsWpS2ypdaQKsZUOoMLQrd0QSFf7Etw6vnB2miZ/PgQ2mN7wnr7vnfGKyYpv8yqyo6naTGnzGKmHA2WVTOY99yRPmEhpI9QGtKTKtw9cje9lvSwKrU3yI5Xrh8lyTBzIBK5VpYrFs3cwcAdtl39SIGJD4CPkT4IXPgXKwBXsvNASXlFk2C5grjBdyIHF0ITBFHo@sfM3cupe67t/juM8/@q8vcBJuI9Q8Q3OXdMm4CvJryjgOIDj@i9o@gY)

Comment: You can't just do `replace(/[^a-z]/g)` because matched characters will be replaced with `'undefined'` (as a string). For instance, `"*abc"` will create the set `Set { 'u', 'n', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'i', 'a', 'b', 'c' }`.

Comment: Was just about to post this myself: [51 bytes](https://tio.run/##BcGxDoIwEADQX7kwtQMlcXBDB2Pi4OZoHM5ytDWlR7gDEn6@vvfDDcUvada28EB17Kv0l0I7vEiNOOUn77TcUMhYN6H6aLo3tsenC9Y6SQd1p3P1XIQzuczBjKZ58A7T6iPwCBoJ7iXkJBEwzxG/pDAwCSCEtFEB0SWVAKvQtbG2/gE)

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 39 bytes

```
Length[Alphabet[]⋂ToLowerCase@#]/26.&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY0xU8JAFIT7/IrnRVMwCDMWdkgYGLWgsKALMPOSvJCDu3vx5SJGx4aWf@kfiYnVzu63s2vRl2TR6wy7YtatyR18mSxMVWJKPtn9Xi8bXvOZZIk1xeFu@vA4ibo30c4n4f1TES9LFMw8Sd3TaBp/B2qrVjqHlhuoGj@ogENLoB30b/DCqSEPXMCzFhrDK4q0862CnmF9ohwyNNa0EzUO1KYP3xudnSAVPjso@BOOja1q4A@S/z2DXy3kfBjqcXh7t49G85vBqOCn@wM)

Answer (score 0):

## MATLAB, 53 bytes

Anonymous function taking a string:

```
@(a)length(unique(upper(a(isstrprop(a,'alpha')))))/26
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>71</s> <s>70</s> 59 bytes

```
Count[Union@ToCharacterCode@ToUpperCase@#,x_/;64<x<91]/26.&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HU3dTsIwGH2VY1EuyMKiMSREDE1m1Esv4EqUfGwdFNZ@s2t10/Dss@Pq/OYcQ/6gDHmdU18@9hkH69/XVrOVK84O5Cj3ymVcqKjXdR05NUqOknabPszuF@1ifvuR3s2m4/7NaevlpEQq8Sc24kkX6DigDn5AB0tGQVvER7zwrlIeXOJZO5XglZzrlhuBmFFzUgVyqkzVTUUCsYrmV9D5CTvHPxYltzgGUzfgb@UuexX9dih4P9Tl6PrmczxZXg1CnPt/)

Thanks to [attinat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/81203/attinat) for suggesting [`Union`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Union.html) to replace [`DeleteDuplicates`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteDuplicates.html).

Comment: `Union` is 11 bytes shorter than `DeleteDuplicates`.

Answer (score 0):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), <s>30</s>, 29 bytes

```
ÓÁ
òóãˆ“±òAÝ/26.0|Óá
C="
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v///Dkw41chzcd3nx48aGOQ42HJh/aeHiT4@G5@kZmegbSNRJA@YVczkK2Qkr//yu5ZKYoVOaXKhSUloDoIoW8xNxUhcw8hZKMVAX3/KSc1BKF/DQFt8yiVB0Fj8Siokp7JQWgVGJxdmqKQnJiTm5OpR4A)

Answer (score 0):

## EXCEL, 55 bytes

Cell `A1` as input. Place in any cell by doing `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter` . +2 bytes if `{}` is included in the count.

```
=SUM(--ISNUMBER(FIND(CHAR(ROW(A65:A91)),UPPER(A1))))/26
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/index.htm), 199 bytes

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION f(s LONG)RETURN FLOAT IS
r FLOAT;BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT c)/26 INTO r
FROM(SELECT LOWER(SUBSTR(s,LEVEL,1))c
FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL<=LENGTH(s))WHERE
c>'`'AND'{'>c;RETURN r;END;
```

More readable version:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION f(s LONG) RETURN FLOAT IS
    r FLOAT;
  BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT c) / 26 INTO r
    FROM (
      SELECT
        LOWER(SUBSTR(s, LEVEL, 1)) AS c
      FROM dual
      CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(s)
    )
    WHERE c > '`' AND '{' > c;
    RETURN r;
  END;
```

Try it on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4cf423/1)!

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell, 86 Bytes

Still golfable, probably.

```
import Data.Char
import Data.List
((/26).toEnum.length.nub.filter isLower.(toLower<$>))
```

Is there any better way to convert an Int to a Float?

Comment: `map toLower` is shorter than `(toLower<$>)`

Answer (score 0):

## [C# .NET](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/), 158 bytes

```
public class P{public static void Main(string[]z){var i=0;for(int q=65;q<91;q++)if(z[0].ToUpper().IndexOf((char)(q))>-1)i++;System.Console.Write(100D/26*i);}}
```

[Try Online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NYE4QI)

Answer (score 0):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 8 bytes

```
▄æl!\╧]▓
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HU3JUcMwFL1TxUtYPMNkaMEcWFIAR5KZb1uWlEj6RksSc6YDhpQAhdCJGxEyp/fmrZaikmz6nKfzx@@3WbxOXz@b6fyZc7V80B1GThhSnNHDkRXQDlEJPHNjRAT3eNJerLAm78d6iWJR2IsOLRlrxrvqonop2lvS7R6N56NDzyfskh0C@CD8/5qh9xEdy5Je8xE2tWqenq1HJ40OCmQGRU257FgEEKQ@CIcQvXYSKYi6dO8vr663N7f1ovAq/wE)

Based on the 05AB1E solution, so be sure to upvote that. I noticed a bug in the "contains" operator, which if resolved would remove the need of the swap.

### Explanation

```
▄          lowercase alphabet as string
 æ         start block of length 4
  l!       push input lowercased
    \      swap top elements
     ╧     pop a, b, a.contains(b)
           loop ends here
      ]    end array / wrap stack in array
       ▓   get average of list
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `spelling`, 44 bytes

```
[ >lower ALPHABET within cardinality 26 /f ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY7NTsMwEITveYoh/BwQKhIHDiBRioAWCSEkyomCtHU2jYljp/aGYFCfPRjoXFbz7e5oSlLi/PD8dPcwPQMFpTVq9pYNQsvGaLtCYAloSCq0nkVi67WVRNcdW8UB51n2nSEpX@TXukB0HdpOfqeHpYahLaRiTN3SsMCVuNWejzAj7@N4kSPtKNRcQJFpTBzl/3HzxNedVjWW3vUWpfvEe9e0Ae6D/V@koa@Iwq22H5e7e/tvB4fjna3Ps83wggvj@nQ/uX@cTa5u5ui1VKmSIl9oS0ZLxMkpjku8Dg21CEKqHg0/)

- `>lower` Convert the input to lowercase.
- `ALPHABET` Place the lowercase alphabet on the data stack.
- `within` Take from the input only those elements that are in the alphabet.
- `cardinality` Count how many elements are in the resulting set.
- `26 /f` Divide by 26 and force the result to be a float.

Answer (score 0):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 72 bytes

```
gsub("[^a-zA-Z]",z)+gsub(z," "){for(;$++a;)b+=!c[tolower($a)]++}$0=b/.26
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcndCoIwGIDhW/kaO3BsWnTQiUgEUV1DYvBNZ4nTxZzIFl37@jl64Xlx6WO8T7NMSHnDNBzSa0VEYPxvQRAg7NUam@SUc8yZ5MWqLp3RZlE2ocgqzt90U8h1tt3FSI5dA97M8JzdrxZGHBR0I7iHgrORWjkwLZw6qwRc0Fq/J/BdOPWqgRr1oH32AQ)

The first bit in this code is a test that's always truthy, so the associated code block will always run no matter what the input string contains.  The purpose of the `gsub` calls is to remove all the non-alphabetic characters and then to split the input string into space separated characters.  That re-evaluates the positional parameters, making the input a list of individual `a-zA-Z` characters.

```
gsub("[^a-zA-Z]",z)+gsub(z," "){                               }
```

The codeblock can then iterate over each positional parameters to process all the alphabetic characters in the input string.

```
                                for(;$++a;)
```

The body of the loop is one AWK statement that does all the real work.  It counts the number of times each unique (lowercase) character is seen.  And anytime the current counter `c[...char...]` is `0` it increments the tally of unique characters.

```
                                           b+=!c[tolower($a)]++
```

Once all the characters have been scanned, the final answer is the tally divided by the number of characters in the alphabet divided by 100.  Assigning that value to `$0` wipes out all the other positional parameters and prints the percentage by default.

```
                                                                $0=b/.26
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
LẠ€Ƈm
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#P2hlYWRlcj0mY29kZT1MJUUxJUJBJUEwJUUyJTgyJUFDJUM2JTg3bSZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PSUyMkRpZCUyMHlvdSUyMHB1dCUyMHlvdXIlMjBuYW1lJTIwaW4lMjB0aGUlMjBHb2JsZXQlMjBvZiUyMEZpcmUlMkMlMjBIYXJyeSUzRiUyMiUyMGhlJTIwYXNrZWQlMjBjYWxtbHkuJmZsYWdzPQ==)

### [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
LỊUl26/
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#P2hlYWRlcj0mY29kZT1MJUUxJUJCJThBVWwyNiUyRiZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PSUyMkRpZCUyMHlvdSUyMHB1dCUyMHlvdXIlMjBuYW1lJTIwaW4lMjB0aGUlMjBHb2JsZXQlMjBvZiUyMEZpcmUlMkMlMjBIYXJyeSUzRiUyMiUyMGhlJTIwYXNrZWQlMjBjYWxtbHkuJmZsYWdzPQ==)

##### Explanations

```python
LẠ€Ƈm  # Implicit input
L      # Lowercase
 Ạ     # Lowercase alphabet
  €    # Single function map:
   Ƈ   #  Contains
    m  # Mean
       # Implicit output
```

```python
LỊUl26/  # Implicit input
L        # Lowercase
 Ị       # Only alphabetic
  U      # Uniquify
   l     # Length
    26/  # Divide by 26
         # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## x86-64 machine code, 47 bytes

Standard x64 System V ABI, signature `long double get_acr(char* str)`. The string is modified by the function, so it cannot be read-only.

```
57 5e 31 c9 ac ff c1 80 66 ff df 84 c0 75 f5 6a 1a df 04 24 5a d9 ee 6a 41 58 57 51 f2 ae 75 04 d9 e8 de c1 59 5f ff c0 ff ca 75 ee de f1 c3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVZdbxs3EHy/X7F1Udhu9emkTiG1KVIYTQO0KNAEzYNlCNSRJzHmkReSJ0sq2r/uzvIoyQ6CptGDdDouh7OzsyQXIqzuVblydHJ/vdAx0OXTm6KY0gvTrMRCRSpd3RgVtbPkRVQYWsXYhMlwWDqpls5UgxBFeas25UrYpRpgwvB9qwJPCcPxd88uRs@GIsP1j3D9BAc8K0JNovQD/u07fnLUr5SpLp8WRVBlWnwQ1SYWhM/SuIUwtFRxjlhGMM4uSbp2YdT@9RnY@K8pRH@OgMoZ4@4CbS6f0utt@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@6wTSUgY2DW1gwLMnJA/QLtgGPRrQrXmA1k/6/szv60B3FgaDmXaG1LIeXmwnX7eKSoq5VyDHCBJcMhPfJPiGOkxZSrzUXs1Pz6OiLy/RcaSNT4pxGc3M0ucxKV0bugB/aGpDCoydFpNFgtCf3VqFCZgv/rdVR2oPY1t1xLSDFLdPJk14hIw05uqgJnb44PTK7/PbIQmweNg0LOnnUlMyMFz70Z3qfmq57fzQMv02KTbIFkzxZfq8aC2uCempE7AE2apPmoGKEwAr6J1@c7Sq8G58/rHTnbKkld0GlU2Avzc6NN/gw8DDauKC5@wZ7nkJKGnPgrkoNamFONnfy6J3e2xZ1GR@edvmpRCPwDoqdkOs/5ccODKgA6XXdhf9AzXNCbB4EZ@ewuWVb88goxwGh@UyOQcUdlYa71UCzXdcd032RMvBjB2YeD6LZB4dgZtER@Dwuj/tLWndwd6diTu9RyOTow@Qor7qtcM@m6xP9cETmPTttVoInWRyi2efdkFQYkpuPsEr7xcNtA8WIeEZ07vWc8hV6WqY68y61rxfTid0mwPtoxScaNz6fJSq2vjsRKmwIPlW8l4qb7R@LQlk5r4W/VX6Ozph3Z8tc27lbvGMvML/buYhz29YLlQ9Y65r7E3qeLxMASTeb4ksIYFpw/D5Eqd1g9bwohkNaliUOCW0HJeVLh6vxQP23whjq//4EABsoZT9xwZgWBTa5BHW2dlqe01@JDXaoqMt0THLc@PoGRpqdzGazkystaeta4isEfj0uQbXanzkvHdaJ5Cr6WXvVo1@E99sfeRphVIRbXFBKYWqzHcxOph9b6iIv9Qbx71uN4i28u7PYNjb0DuLhCFyno5GPtd0WqS0ZqfMRbiexOpudfPVrNZvZ2UnvkDIncX4@/R9hF/uwfUFRcBpNi78LlKfTvCj@8@L36eIMhnW6/2VDUP@K@r@BlDLdjPt/AQ)

### Explanation

```
; long double get_acr(char* str)
; follows x64 SysV ABI
; input RDI: null-delimited writable string (gets modified)
; output ST0: percentage in range [0, 1]
get_acr:
    ; Get string length in rcx and convert characters to uppercase
    push rdi
    pop rsi ; get str reference in rsi
    xor ecx, ecx ; len = 0

__get_acr_convlp:
    lodsb ; get byte into rsi

    ; non-zero char: increment length and handle conversion
    ; if it is zero, we increment, do (effectively) no conversions, and store 
    ; back. this +1 in ecx doesn't matter though, since it's okay if we search
    ; for letters in the zero byte later on.
    inc ecx

    ; convert by removing bit for 32 to force lowercase letters uppercase
    ; in other words, and al by ~32 (0b1101 1111, 0xdf).
    and byte [rsi-1], 0xdf
    
    ; loop back up if al != 0
    test al, al
    jnz __get_acr_convlp

    ; init counter rdx: do 26 times
    ; also get 26 into st1 for division later
    push 26
    fild word [rsp]
    pop rdx

    fldz ; sum starts at 0.0

    ; We only have uppercase letters now to look for
    ; Initial letter: 'A'
    push 65
    pop rax

__get_acr_loop:
    push rdi ; save rdi
    push rcx ; save rcx

    ; rcx times: search for al
    repne scasb ; go until rcx = 0 or found al (zf = 1)

    ; add 1 if zf, do nothing otherwise
    jnz __get_acr_dno

    fld1
    faddp

__get_acr_dno:
    pop rcx ; restore rcx
    pop rdi ; restore rdi

    inc eax ; next letter

    dec edx
    jnz __get_acr_loop ; loop back to top edx times

    ; Divide st0 by st1 and pop to get the fraction to return
    fdivrp st1, st0

    ret
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Racket](https://racket-lang.org) – 115 bytes

```rkt
(~r(*(/(set-count(apply set(filter char-alphabetic?(string->list(string-upcase(read-line))))))26)100)#:precision 2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcyxDoIwEIDhVznC0po0IoODg668xlkO2tC0zfUqYfHVkWj8t2/5Ge1CsrcB4wz8g3qzOqmzKiTGphpFYc5hg8Nq8kGIwTpkgyE7fJJ4@1BF2MfZ3IMv8kfNFgspJhxN8JH0t/6qL12n21tmsr74FKHX@z7QBuKIqYEhZYItVXD4IkBYUxyJpxpgJVoA3TFsPg)

---

### Explanation

First, we read user input and transform it into upper case. We then turn the string into a list of characters and remove any characters that aren't alphabetic. Once done, we transform the list into a set. A Set is a data structure that can only contain unique values. That's cool because it allows us to simply count the number of elements in the set and calculate the percentage of unique letters that are used. Once all is done, we return the result as a decimal string with the precision of 2.

```rkt
(~r (* (/ (set-count (apply set
                            (filter char-alphabetic?
                                    (string->list (string-upcase (read-line))))))
           26)
       100)
    #:precision 2)
```

Some cool things to note that I just found out is that Racket uses fractions by default to calculate large arbitrary precision. If you were to remove `~r` you'd see a fraction that looks like `x/y`.

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 72 bytes

*Outputs via exit code*

```c
r;a[];main(c){return~c?main(getchar(r+=a[c&=95]++<c/65-c/91)):r/.26+.5;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcndCoJAEEDhVxm8CGVTKVAwE2@iegfxYhpXXVrXGFdCoh697efqwHco7Iic4xyrOh9QGZ@CB0s7s3lR@YdOWuqRfRYFVrQqsqQWYk9xmoQUZ5sg2HEcbVMRJfnTOe@gGljGGW6z/ZXB4CBBGbC9hNN40dLC2MJRsVzDGZmX0oPvwukqGyDUg16iN7Uau8mF9w8)

### Commented

```c
r;                // int r is zero-initialized
a[];              // same for int array a[]; it has size 1 (we'll pretend it's 96)
main(c){          // function main returns int and takes an int `c`
 return
  ~c?             // if c != -1:
   main(          //  call main() recursively with
    getchar(      //   next character from stdin or EOF(-1) (ignores argument)
     r+=          //    add the following to r:
      a[c&=95]++  //     uppercase `c`, increment the value at it's index in a[]
       <c/65-c/91 //     if (old value of a[c]) < (c/'A' - c/'[') add 1, else 0
    )             //   end call to getchar()
   )              //  end call to main()
  :               // else (we're at the end):
   r/.26+.5;      //  return the accumulated result as a % of 26, rounded
}                 // end main() function
```

### Explanation

Alphabetic characters are in the ranges \$1000001_2..1011010_2\$ (uppercase) and \$1100001_2..1111010_2\$ (lowercase), and \$95_{10} = 1011111_2\$, so
`c &= 95` makes characters uppercase and changes symbols in some way we don't care as they will not land in the same range.

For \$0 \le c \le 95\$ the equation \$\frac{c}{65} - \frac{c}{91}\$ returns 1 if \$65 \le c \le 90\$ (c is uppercase) and 0 otherwise.

So `a[c &= 95]++ < c/65 - c/91` checks that `isapha(c)` and that this is the first time we see `c` in uppercase or lowercase (by incrementing the value we make sure subsequent occurrences of `c` will not match the expression).

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala 3](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 50 bytes

```scala
_.filter(_.isLetter).toLowerCase.distinct.size/26f
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XU5LTgJBEN1zipdezSQwJpgYQ4LGaNAFrtQVGNLMVGNDTzd21wCD4SRucKFX8CzcwiPYMjs39arqffLev0IujTz9HokObZZGaivaEB3r1tJb8Xz4cdM55Yz7yOCtBRSkUMYjkX4WerjyXtajB_bazp7THp6sZvSPSmAZv2xsohIxFje6QO0qLCv-Qw8rS0JM5RfCrZsaYjiFgfbUxp30vr4cC0ROhgUViDVLU2ciTf9HP0bNa6XzBaberS2U22BelcsAtyJ_jDdyW6Nws8a9a8Wxkgaqh6Sp3r8YGCc5Rf-zYtU5P3QnmdKGySeTTIchcVzTjN3Qrclfy0BZoQNrm3MW9JZOumeqcX7sGtzvG_wF)